# PHP $_GET in plain html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, get

I am trying to figure out how to get the parts of a URL I am going to be receiving from a third-party website. The URL I am expecting is something like: `index.html?lob=company&ZipCode=22407`

All of my pages are coded in `.html` rather than PHP due to my client's needs/desires, so my question is how can I get the "ZipCode" value.

In PHP this would be super simple, however I cannot do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Javascript instead.

```
var value_of_zipcode = "index.html?lob=company&ZipCode=22407".match("ZipCode=([0-9]{5})")[1];
```

now the **value_of_zipcode** is 22407